# How to configure folder with pip files as local pip repository

Tags: python

I have station which disconnect from the internet.

I manually download the packages I need (I took the packages names and version from pip freeze) and put them under `MyPip` folder

Now I want to be able to configure this folder as a local pip repository.

I want to be able to run the following command `pip install pandas` and `pandas` will be installed from `MyPip` repository folder.
(I am using python 3.6)

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you looked into virtual environments and packages like [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/)

Comment: `pip install /MyPip/path/to/pandas.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the `--find-links` flag (add `--no-index` to not use pypi.org at all):

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=MyPip pandas
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages